# Error importing PyTorch XLA on Google Colab

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, torch, tpu

I am trying to run some code on Google Colab TPU.

I am installing pytorch-xla using the following lines of code:

```
!pip install cloud-tpu-client==0.10 https://storage.googleapis.com/tpu-pytorch/wheels/torch_xla-1.9-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

When I am trying to import torch_xla, I am getting the error

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/_XLAC.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK2at10TensorBase8data_ptrIN3c107complexIfEEEEPT_v
```

What is the reason for this error and what is the solution?

This issue is occurring even when using the example notebooks given in pytorch-xla github repo readme. But I received no error yesterday running the same notebooks!

EDIT:

When I run the following code:

```
!curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/xla/master/contrib/scripts/env-setup.py -o pytorch-xla-env-setup.py
!python pytorch-xla-env-setup.py --version 1.9
import os
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']='/usr/local/lib'
!echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
!sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.so /usr/local/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.so.1
!sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libmkl_intel_thread.so /usr/local/lib/libmkl_intel_thread.so.1
!sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libmkl_core.so /usr/local/lib/libmkl_core.so.1
!ldconfig
!ldd /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so
```

It uninstalls torch-1.9.0+cu102 and install torch-1.10.0a0+git88c0ea9

When importing torch I get this output

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/package/_directory_reader.py:17: UserWarning: Failed to initialize NumPy: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd (Triggered internally at  /pytorch/torch/csrc/utils/tensor_numpy.cpp:68.)
  _dtype_to_storage = {data_type(0).dtype: data_type for data_type in _storages}
```

What is the reason behind this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

```
%pip install cloud-tpu-client==0.10 https://storage.googleapis.com/tpu-pytorch/wheels/torch_xla-1.9-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl

%pip install torch==1.9.0+cu111 torchvision==0.10.0+cu111 torchtext==0.10.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu111/torch_stable.html
```